# Hiding button on desktop browser and showing only on mobile devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap header nav bar with buttons. What I trying to do is to add button which is visible only on mobile devices and small screens - phones/tablets.

This is structure of the header

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                <li><a href="">Button 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Button 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Button 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">BUTTON 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I want to make `BUTTON 4` visible only on small screens. 
So I make the button like this:

```
<li class="not_visible"><a href="">BUTTON 4</a></li>
```

Then in css I add

```
.not_visible {
    display: none;
}
@media  (max-width: 767px) {
    .header{
        text-align : center;
    }

    .not_visible {
        display: inline;
    }                                                                                                                          

   .nav{
        margin-top : 30px;
   }
}
```

But is visible on every screen resolution. Seems like `display: none;` isn't working.

Comment: Not me. I just approved one edition but doesn't saw the tag. Now I removed the tag again ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using bootstrap, you can use visible-xs class on them:

```
<li class="visible-xs"><a href="">BUTTON 4</a></li>
```

Now, it will be visible in xs-devices and hidden in other devices.

Comment: Oh, that was easy. It is working. Just a question what are exactly `xs-devices`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will accept your answer in 10min when countdown end :)

Answer (score 1):

BUTTON 4
is best approach however if you do not follow bootstrap then simply you can use display:inline !important;

As the css which is lower on page has more priority and in your case I think there is some hierarchy problem.

Try this deisplay:inline !important;

Answer (score 0):

It is probably late but since I noticed you are using bootstrap you can use `.d-block .d-sm-none` as your class to make it only visible on `xs-` small devices.

[Use this as a guide.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/)